# Awarding bounty when no one replies

Tags: support, bounties

I have a question on which I set a bounty.  No one answered and the bounty period has expired.  I get a message on the question page asking me to award the bounty to someone within 23 hours.  Who do I award it to?  How do I award it?  No one replied to the question so how is it possible to award it to anyone?

Comment: What question was it on? There are around 300-400 questions with bounties on SO, and I still see some questions (specifically in the java section, there are 2) without answers after a week of a 200 rep bounty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to award it to anyone. If nobody answers within 23 hours, just let it expire. That's it. No harm done.

Comment: There was a comment though, does that count?

Comment: Nope. You can't award it to a comment(er). Should their particular comment have been something that can be turned into a good constructive answer, you can ask them to do so. But if not, then there's not much that can be done.

Comment: No, comments are not answers, so they do not count.

Comment: thanks for your help.

Comment: Just faced a similar issue - not only I had to figure out the answer myself, I also ended up loosing points I put up as bounty. Everyone works hard for those points and wasting them sucks. Why can't bounty be given back to a user if there is only one answer by OP? Or no answers at all?