# Message invites users to award a bounty that cannot be awarded at the time the message appears

Tags: feature-request, bounties

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148309/awarding-bounty-when-no-one-replies) was the result of confusion for a user.  He was instructed to award a bounty within the next day, but there were no answers, so he could not award the bounty.

Maybe the message could be clearer to cover this edge case?

Or the software can suppress display of that message for, say, 12 hours, and check again then to see if there are answers to the bountified question?